# How to solve ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error while trying to connect Jenkins via AWS ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, devops, cicd

I am not able to connect to Jenkins via AWS ec2 ubuntu instance. I have also added the security group for the port 8080. But I only got this one error:

```
xx.xx.xx.xxx refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: Do you have a load balancer in front? does your ec2 sit inside a private or public subnet? can you share the security group rules you've configured?

Comment: Does it fail immediately (indicating refusal) or does it take a while to fail (indicating lack of network connectivity)? "Refused to connect" sounds like it is connecting but being rejected.

Comment: sgr-0862d640010dcef35  Custom  TCP  TCP  8080  0.0.0.0/0 (MY IP)
i-0174e787d568693fb (jenkins-master)
PublicIPs: 52.91.166.63    PrivateIPs: 172.31.93.146
I am trying to connect 52.91.166.63/8080

Comment: It fails immediately

Comment: Hi @AllanChua
Can you please help me out in this?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Can you SSH to the server and observe if the Jenkins server is running? How are you connecting to your Jenkins server?

Comment: Hi @AllanChua I used `sudo systemctl status jenkins` to see the jenkins status. It shows active and running
And then I am using AWS public ip 52.91.166.63/8080 to log in to the jenkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried accessing your Jenkins server using my personal computer using the following URL http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8080 (Pay attention to the syntax of port, I've used `:` instead of a `/`) and it opens without a problem.

[image]

Please do try it with your mobile phone as well. Now if the problem continues to persists, there maybe some network rules that prevents you from visiting the Jenkins server for security purposes. Please approach your networking guy at work if that's the case.

Comment: Wow! That was easy. Sorry I am new to this. It was silly I guess. But thanks a lot!